# Sumbit button also used as a navlink to route page, does not sumbt the form unless it is not used as a navlink in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-router-dom

I have a form with a button to submit it, and I also use the same button to route to another page.
the button work in routing and when I remove the Navlink tag it submits the form. but it does not submit it when the Navlink tags are there and does not show the validation error msgs as well it just route the page.

any help on how to get the two actions to work?

here is my code

```
import react, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faEyeSlash, faEye } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import './sign.css';

const Sign = () => {
    //state to be sent to backend
    const intialValues = { firstname: "", lastname: "", mobile: "", email: "", password: "", cpassword: "" };

    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(intialValues);
    const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});
    const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
    }

    const handleSubmit = (err) => {
        err.preventDefault();
        setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
        setIsSubmit(true);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
            console.log(formValues);
        }
    }, [formErrors])

    const validate = (values) => {
        const errors = {};
  

        if (!values.firstname) {
            errors.firstname = 'firstname is required!';
        }
        if (!values.lastname) {
            errors.lastname = 'lastname is required!';
  }
        return errors;
    }


    return (

        <div className='signup'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                <div className="container">
                    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                    <div className="name">
                        <div>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="First name"
                                name="firstname"
                                id='firstName'
                                value={formValues.firstname}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Last name"
                                name="lastname"
                                value={formValues.lastname}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        </div>



                    </div>
                    <p className='errorMsg'>{formErrors.firstname}</p>
                    <p className='errorMsg'>{formErrors.lastname}</p>
                    <br />
                   
                    <div className="clearfix">
                        <NavLink to='/profileclient'>
                            <button type="submit" className="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                        </NavLink>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}




export default Sign;
```

then I tried to use useNavigate so I modified these lines, and it does navigate to the other page but in the console, it gives me a warning "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected", it does not log the state objects.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
 <div className="clearfix">
<button type="submit" className="signupbtn" onClick={() => { navigate('/profileclient') }}>Sign Up</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: What about use `navigate('/profileclient')`  at the end of `handleSubmit` ?

Comment: This is why you don't nest an interactable element within an interactable element, the expected behavior is ambiguous, especially when one prevents the other from working correctly. What exactly is the code trying to accomplish?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette  did not work.

Comment: @DrewReese i am trying to make a button which submit the form and then navigate to another page.

Comment: The important keywords are ***submit the form and then navigate***. On click of the button, the form submit needs time to accomplish. And a navigation too. You attempt to trigger both at the same time. -- About my solution.. *"did not work"* is not giving me any hint about what to tell you. Do you use the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) at least?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the solution.
the main problem was that I tried to trigger functions at the same time by clicking on a button, while the submission needs time first before the navigation could happen, this is why it did not submit the form but only navigated. in order to solve the ambiguous behavior, I have put the navigation function call in if statement to make sure the submission is done or not before the navigation is executed. I have also changed the place where I call the navigate function, rather than calling it on the button onClick attribute, I placed it in the useEffect where I check if there are no errors you can submit the form and after submitting it you can navigate to another page.

this is the part of my code that made it work well.

```
            if (isSubmit) {
                return (navigate('/profileclient'));
}
```

and here is my full code

```
import react, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavLink, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faEyeSlash, faEye } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import './sign.css';

const SignC = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    //state to be sent to backend
    const intialValues = { firstname: "", lastname: "", mobile: "", email: "", password: "", cpassword: "" };

    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(intialValues);
    const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});
    const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);
    const [passwordShown, setPasswordShowen] = useState(false);
    const [cPasswordShown, setCPasswordShowen] = useState(false);
    const [eyeShowen, setEyeShowen] = useState(false);
    const [cEyeShowen, setCEyeShowen] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
    }

    const handleSubmit = (err) => {
        err.preventDefault();
        setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
        setIsSubmit(true);
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
            console.log(formValues);
            if (isSubmit) {
                return (navigate('/profileclient'));
            }

        }
    }, [formErrors])

    const validate = (values) => {
        const errors = {};
        const regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/i;

        if (!values.firstname) {
            errors.firstname = 'firstname is required!';
        }
        if (!values.lastname) {
            errors.lastname = 'lastname is required!';
        }
        if (!values.mobile) {
            errors.mobile = 'mobile is required!';
        }
        if (!values.email) {
            errors.email = 'email is required!';
        } else if (!regex.test(values.email)) {
            errors.email = 'this is not a valid email format!'
        }
        if (!values.password) {
            errors.password = 'password is required!';
        } else if (values.password.length < 4) {
            errors.password = 'password must be more than 4 characters';
        } else if (values.password.length > 10) {
            errors.password = 'password must not exceeds 10 characters';
        }
        if (!values.cpassword) {
            errors.cpassword = 'password confirmation is required!';
        } else if (values.cpassword != values.password) {
            errors.cpassword = 'confirmation password does not match!';
        }
        return errors;
    }

    const togglePassword = () => {
        setPasswordShowen(!passwordShown);
        toggleEye();
    }
    const toggleCPassword = () => {
        setCPasswordShowen(!cPasswordShown);
        toggleCEye();
    }

    const toggleEye = () => {
        setEyeShowen(!eyeShowen);
    }
    const toggleCEye = () => {
        setCEyeShowen(!cEyeShowen);
    }

    return (

        <div className='signup'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                <div className="container">
                    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                    <div className="name">
                        <div>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="First name"
                                name="firstname"
                                id='firstName'
                                value={formValues.firstname}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Last name"
                                name="lastname"
                                value={formValues.lastname}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        </div>



                    </div>
                    <p className='errorMsg'>{formErrors.firstname}</p>
                    <p className='errorMsg'>{formErrors.lastname}</p>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Business mobile number"
                            name="mobile"
                            value={formValues.mobile}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <p className='errorMsg'>{formErrors.mobile}</p>
                        <br />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Email Adress"
                            name="email"
                            value={formValues.email}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <p className='errorMsg'>{formErrors.email}</p>
                        <br />
                        <div className="password">
                            <input
                                type={passwordShown ? 'text' : 'password'}
                                placeholder="Password"
                                name="password"
                                id='password'
                                value={formValues.password}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                icon={eyeShowen ? faEye : faEyeSlash}
                                id='togglePassword'
                                onClick={togglePassword}
                            />
                            <p className='errorMsg'>{formErrors.password}</p>

                            <br />
                            <input
                                type={cPasswordShown ? 'text' : 'password'}
                                placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                name="cpassword"
                                id='Cpassword'
                                value={formValues.cpassword}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                icon={cEyeShowen ? faEye : faEyeSlash}
                                id='toggleCPassword'
                                onClick={toggleCPassword}
                            />
                            <p className='errorMsg'>{formErrors.cpassword}</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" className="check" />i’ve read and agree with <a href="url" >Terms of service</a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="clearfix">
                        <button type="submit" className="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form >
        </div >
    )
}




export default SignC;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to make a button which submit the form and then navigate
> to another page.

The important distinction here is the ***then***. When you wrap a link around a button both elements are clicked.

```
<NavLink to='/profileclient'>
  <button type="submit" className="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
</NavLink>
```

The link tries to navigate at the same time the form is processing its `onSubmit` handler.

If you want to conditionally navigate at the after submitting the form then you need to move the navigation logic there. Use the `useHistory` or `useNavigate` (*depending on `react-router-dom` version, v5 the former, v6 the latter*). There's also no need to store an `isSubmit` state, you can simply check the validation result in the submit handler and conditionally set the form errors ***or*** navigate to the next page.

Example:

```
const Sign = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const errors = validate(formValues);
    if (Object.values(errors).length) {
      setFormErrors(errors);
    } else {
      navigate("/profileclient");
    }
  };

  const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    ...
    return errors;
  };

  return (
    <div className="signup">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="container">
          <h1>Sign Up</h1>
          ...

          <div className="clearfix">
            <button type="submit" className="signupbtn">
              Sign Up
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```